# Windows Batch File: How to dynamically pick up input filenames and also use as the output filename?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file on Windows to run this psiblast application.
An example of the command is as follows:

```
psiblast -db swissprot -query ./seq/C3W5S7.FASTA -out ./out/C3W5S7.FASTA
```

The input is the '-query' option and output is the '-out' option.

I have a folder 'seq' that contains all the input data files to query the application. The input files are all named with their unique IDs (e.g. in this case, C3W5S7). How can I pick up this filename dynamically and similarly use it as the filename in the output?

Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\*.fasta") DO IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxb" ECHO psiblast -db swissprot -query "%%b" -out "%destdir%\%%~nxb"
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that if you use fixed absolute source and destination names, you can run this batch regardless of your current directory. If you change those names to `".\seq" ".\out"` then the directories will be relative to your current directory.

The `if not exist` statement will **NOT** run the conversion if the destination filename already exists. This is obviously optional.

Note that the `psiblast` command is merely `Echo`ed for testing purposes. Remove that `echo` keyword to run `psiblast` as listed.

If `psiblast` is a batch file, replace `ECHO` with `CALL` to execute it.